# bloques de 15 dias en sql en R

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

id
              dinero
              fecha

1
              15
              2009-02-07

1
              30
              2009-02-09

1
              45
              2009-03-04

1
              50
              2009-03-12

Me gustaría obtener el máximo de dinero gastado en cada quincena. Por ejemplo para la primera quincena de febrero tendría que salir 30 y para la de Marzo 50. ¿Cómo podría hacer esto en una consulta sql en R con la librería sqldf?

No utilizo ninguna base de datos, los tengo en archivos .csv y los importo en un dataframe. El problema que tendría es que el periodo de tiempo en el que tengo que realizar esto abarca varios años por lo que no sabría muy bien como realizarlo.

Comment: Podrias aclarar a que base de datos te referis? eso puede variar un poco las funciones a utilizar para calcular la quincena que buscas.

Comment: Gracias, por contestar tan rápido. Estoy utilizando sql pero en el programa R con la librería sqldf.

Comment: ok.. agrega la etiqueta R entonces.. y no se como funciona el sql ahi.. :( probablemente tengas alguna funcion que cuente que quincena del año es, las puedas numerar y despues agrupar por ellas?

Comment: bah.. estas yendo contra alguna base de datos conocida?

Comment: No utilizo ninguna base de datos, los tengo en archivos .csv y los importo en un dataframe. El problema que tendría es que el periodo de tiempo en el que tengo que realizar esto abarca varios años por lo que no sabría muy bien como realizarlo.

Comment: año, numero de quincena en el año es tu clave de agrupamiento...y aclara todo lo que estas comentando en la pregunta.

Comment: Como comenta @gbianchi deberás agrupar por quincena y año ,para evitar problemas. Con MySql es relativamente sencillo

Comment: Como se haría eso, estoy intentando crear una secuencia que contenga las quincenas entre un determinado periodo de tiempo pero de esta manera no lo consigo. ¿Cómo podría agrupar por quincena y año?

Comment: @adamista   Nunca he tocado SQLDF, si quieres puedo contestarte con una aproximación suponiendo que el backend sea SQLite (que creo que por defecto es el que suele ser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No he tocado SQLDF,asique pongo esto para que pueda servirte de guia y/o ayuda.Suponiendo que el backend de sqldf sea SQLite, la select que estas buscando podría ser igual o similar a la siguiente

```
Select MAX(dinero) Cantidad,
   ROUND(strftime('%W', fecha)/2) Quincena,
   strftime('%Y', fecha) Year
   from quincenas
   group by ROUND(strftime('%W', fecha)/2),strftime('%Y', fecha)
```

Sobre el funcionamiento, strftime lo utilizamos para sacar por separado la semana del año con %W y el año en concreto con %Y.

Comment: Gracias, he probado con el código que me proporcionas, adaptándolo a sql, y las quincenas que me genera son solamente a las que pertenecen dichas fechas. Yo querría que aunque no hubiese datos para esas fechas, apareciese la quincena y el año con el campo a 0 del máximo.

Comment: Otra cosa, al ejecutarlo, el año me indica que es -467 en todos los casos, por lo que creo que el strftime para el año no me lo realiza bien, sin embargo, para la quincena si que funciona.

Comment: Ok, nada, era cosa del formato en el que tenía las fechas. Ya funciona, gracias :D

Comment: @adamista Me alegra ver que te sirvió. Has tenido que hacer muchas modificaciones?

Comment: No, antes de renombrar las columnas indiqué un "as". Por ejemplo puse: ROUND(strftime('%W', fecha)/2) as Quincena. Gracias :D

Answer (score 1):

Propongo una solución usando `tidyverse` y `lubridate` que contempla que devuelva todas las quincenas (aunque no haya datos para esa quincena) y además considera quincenas que van del 1-15 y del 15-último día del mes.

Construyo el ejemplo:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4, 5, 6), 
                 dinero = c(15, 30, 45, 50, 10, 20), 
                 fecha = as.Date(c("2009-02-15", "2009-02-07", "2009-02-09",
                                   "2009-03-04", "2009-03-12", "2015-07-31")))
id dinero      fecha
 1     15 2009-02-15
 2     30 2009-02-07
 3     45 2009-02-09
 4     50 2009-03-04
 5     10 2009-03-12
 6     20 2015-07-31
```

Ahora genero un dataframe que tenga todos los últimos días de quincena, desde la fecha en que empieza a haber datos en `df` hasta la fecha en que termina, agregando una columna que se llame `dinero`, con el valor `0` para todas las fechas (que la voy a usar luego):

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

dates <- as_tibble(seq(floor_date(as.Date(min(df$fecha)), unit = "month"), 
                       ceiling_date(as.Date(max(df$fecha)), unit = "month"), 
                       by = 'days')) %>% 
  mutate(dinero = 0) %>% 
  filter(day(value) == 15 |
         day(value) == day(ceiling_date(value, unit = "month") - 1))

# A tibble: 156 × 2
        value dinero
       <date>  <dbl>
1  2009-02-15      0
2  2009-02-28      0
3  2009-03-15      0
4  2009-03-31      0
5  2009-04-15      0
6  2009-04-30      0
7  2009-05-15      0
8  2009-05-31      0
9  2009-06-15      0
10 2009-06-30      0
# ... with 146 more rows
```

`floor_date` con `unit = "month"` toma el primer día del mes (`1`) y `ceiling_date() - 1` toma el último (pudiendo ser 28, 29, 30 o 31).

Después hago un `full_join`, y considero `dinero` si `df$dinero` no es `NA` y si no `dates$dinero`, que definí como 0 para todos los casos.

```
resultado <- df %>% 
  full_join(dates, by = c("fecha" = "value")) %>% 
  mutate(year = year(fecha),
         month = month(fecha),
         num_quin = ifelse(1 <= day(fecha) & day(fecha)<=15, 1, 2),
         dinero = ifelse(!is.na(dinero.x), dinero.x, dinero.y)) %>% 
  group_by(year, month, num_quin) %>% 
  summarize(max_dinero = max(dinero))

Source: local data frame [156 x 4]
Groups: year, month [?]

    year month num_quin max_dinero
   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
1   2009     2        1         45
2   2009     2        2          0
3   2009     3        1         50
4   2009     3        2          0
5   2009     4        1          0
6   2009     4        2          0
7   2009     5        1          0
8   2009     5        2          0
9   2009     6        1          0
10  2009     6        2          0
# ... with 146 more rows
```

Ahí te queda ordenado por año, mes y quincena 1 o 2 del mes.